# Is there ArgumentsType<T> like ReturnType<T> in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

`ReturnType<T>` extracts return type of a function.

Is there a way to define `ArgumentsType<T>` that extracts parameter types of a function in `tuple` format?

For example,

`ArgumentsType<(a: number, b: string) => boolean>` will be `[number, string]`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

#### Typescript 3.1

Since writing the original answer, typescript now has a built-in type (defined in `lib.d.ts`) to get the type of the parameters called [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype).

```js
type argsEmpty = Parameters<() => void> 
// []

type args = Parameters<(x: number, y: string, z: boolean) => void> 
// [number, string, boolean]

type argsOpt = Parameters<(x: number, y?: string, z?: boolean) => void> 
// [number, (string | undefined)?, (boolean | undefined)?]
```

#### Original answer

**Edit** Typescript 3.0 has been released the code below works as expected.

While this is not possible in the current version of typescript (2.9) without spelling out all parameters. It will become possible in the next version of typescript (3.0) which will be released in the next few days:

```js
type ArgumentsType<T> = T extends (...args: infer U) => any ? U: never;

type argsEmpty = ArgumentsType<() => void> 
// []

type args = ArgumentsType<(x: number, y: string, z: boolean) => void>
// [number, string, boolean]

type argsOpt = ArgumentsType<(x: number, y?: string, z?: boolean) => void> 
// [number, (string | undefined)?, (boolean | undefined)?]
```

If you install `npm install typescript@next` you can already play with this, it should be available sometime this month.

**Note**

We can also spread a tuple into arguments with this new feature:

```js
type Spread<T extends any[]> = (...args: T) => void;

type Func = Spread<args> 
// (x: number, y: string, z: boolean) => void
```

You can read more about this feature [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897)

Comment: Looking forward to it! Thank you!

Comment: @Joon Yup me too, I'm going to have to rewrite a lot of answers, this features makes everything simpler :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Just wondering. What if I need to get the parameter types of a function inside a class. In other words how do I use `Parameters` inside a class? [This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20myClass%20%7B%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a(param%3A%20string)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b(param%3A%20Parameters%3Cthis.a%3E%20%5B0%5D)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20a(param)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D) should make it clearer

Comment: @NahushFarkande You need to use `Parameters<ClassName['methodName']>` don't forget to upvote useful answers ;)

Comment: @NahushFarkande for your example `b(param: Parameters<myClass['a']> [0])` or `b(param: Parameters<this['a']> [0])` (but I would avoid polymorphic this usually.

Answer (score 10):

As of TypeScript 3.1, `Parameters` type is now a part of the standard library.

```
type Result = Parameters<(a: number, b: string) => boolean>; // [number, string]
```

Comment: What version? Doesn't seem to be in 3.0.1

Comment: The [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26243) doesn't mention any milestone, but it is most definitely there in TypeScript 3.1.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way for now to extract both the types *and* amount of arguments for any function possible. But you can try something like this:

```
type ArgumentTypes<T> = T extends () => any ? never[] :
                        T extends (a1: infer T1) => any ? [T1] :
                        T extends (a1: infer T1, a2: infer T2) => any ? [T1, T2] :
                        // continue here for any reasonable number of args
                        never;
```

Check it with the following:

```
const args0: ArgumentTypes<() => boolean> = []; // correct
const args1: ArgumentTypes<(a: number) => boolean> = [1]; // correct
const args2: ArgumentTypes<(a: number, b: string) => boolean> = [1, 'str']; // correct

const oops0null: ArgumentTypes<() => boolean> = null; // error, arguments are array (but empty one)
const oops01: ArgumentTypes<() => boolean> = [1]; // error, arguments must be empty

const oops10: ArgumentTypes<(a: number) => boolean> = []; // error, we need one argument
const oops12: ArgumentTypes<(a: number) => boolean> = [1, 2]; // error, we need only one argument
const oops1wrong: ArgumentTypes<(a: number) => boolean> = ['str']; // error, argument must be number

const oops21: ArgumentTypes<(a: number, b: string) => boolean> = [1]; // error, we need two arguments
const oops23: ArgumentTypes<(a: number, b: string) => boolean> = [1, 'str', undefined]; // error, we need only two arguments
const oops2wrong: ArgumentTypes<(a: number, b: string) => boolean> = ['str', 1]; // error, arguments are reversed
```

Note that this don't have any use of optional arguments - they are just omitted from the output. I wasn't able to find a way to catch them for now.

Comment: This can be useful before 3.0. Thank you!

Comment: @Joon even after 3 it helps with an open issue in TypeScript with [function overloads](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28172) where someone else came up with a [similar workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26591#issuecomment-478906769)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are many uses for `Parameters<T>` but I wanted a way to provide proxy method to the same method on a private member and it seemed a perfect fit.

eg. I want to have the following, such that if the `authService.login` signature changes I don't have to modify my proxy - just whatever is calling it.

```
login(username: string, password: string) { this.authService.login(username, password); }
```

With `Parameters<T>` you can do the following

```
login = (...params: Parameters<AuthService['login']>) => this.authService.login(...params);
```

Of course the benefit is that if you have complex parameters it'll just take care of itself nicely - (probably wouldn't recommend this for just two strings!)

It took me a couple attempts to figure out that I needed `...` on both occurrences of `params`.

Answer (score 1):

For my issue, I used the below style:

```js
const myFunction = <T>(items: T[], config: FuseConfigType) => {
  const fuse = new Fuse(items, config);

  return (pattern: string): T[] =>
    pattern === '' ? items : fuse.search(pattern).map(({ item }) => item);
};

export default fuseSearch;
```

I get the `T` type, the type of each item inside items and then when I want to return the function I use the `T` to pass it just like I get it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a collection of common helper types like this: https://github.com/joonhocho/tsdef

Here's you can find many helper patterns for typescript.
you can install via npm or yarn as well.
`npm i -D tsdef`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [@Titian Cernicova-Dragomir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51300048/5950725), if you are using named function expressions, thus not being able to define a type, you can access the parameters with `typeof` like so:

```js
function updateTable<T extends IHasOBJECT_ID>(
  diff: Diff,
  cache: { [id: string]: Table<T, Array<keyof T>> & IHasOBJECT_ID & IHasCONFLICTS & IHasOPTIONS },
) {
  // Use typeof to get the parameter type for cache
  const cacheItem: Parameters<typeof updateTable>[1] = cache[diff.id];

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function arguments are on a `class`, then you can use the following to extract them:

```
class Foo {
  bar(a: string, b: number) {
    // Want these ^
  }
}

type BarFn = Foo['bar']; 
//     ^  (a: string, b: number) => void
type BarFnArguments = Parameters<BarFn>;
//     ^  [string, number]
type FirstArg  = BarFnArguments[0]
//     ^  string
type SecondArg  = BarFnArguments[1]
//     ^  number
```

Useful for unit-test mocks, which can be untyped sometimes with jest.