# Extract return type and arguments types of a generic type

Tags: typescript, redux

In order to make it meaningful lets take a look at this mini naive implementation of what could look like react useReducer

```js
type Reducer<S, A> = (prevState: S, action: A) => S;
type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;

function useReducer<S, A>(reducer: Reducer<S, A>, initState: S): [getState: () => S, dispatcher: Dispatch<A>] {
  let state = initState;

  return [
    () => state, 
    action => state = reducer(state, action)
  ];
}

// its working as expected (but that is not the question)
type CountActions =
  | { type: "inc" }
  | { type: "dec" }
  | { type: "reset"; payload?: number };

const [getState, dispatch] = useReducer<number, CountActions>(
  (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === "inc") {
      return state + 1;
    }
    if (action.type === "dec") {
      return state - 1;
    }
    if (action.type === "reset") {
      return action?.payload ?? 0;
    }
    return state;
  },
  0
)
getState()//0
dispatch({ type: 'inc' })
dispatch({ type: 'inc' })
getState()//2
dispatch({ type: 'dec' })
getState()//1
dispatch({ type: 'reset', payload: 2 })
getState()//2
dispatch({ type: 'reset' })
getState()//0
```

My question is: is there a way to write inner types of useReducer only deriving a single entry, the Reducer type ?

How would you write `ExtractSFrom` and `ExtractAFrom` ?

```js
// ideally I want to have something that is defined like the real thing ;)

function useReducer<R>(reducer: R, initState: ExtractSFrom<R>): [getState: () => ExtractSFrom<R>, dispatcher: (value: ExtractAFrom<A>) => void] {
  let state = initState;

  return [
    () => state, 
    action => state = reducer(state, action)
  ];
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your second code example does type `R` have any constraints? I assume you want it to be constrained to extending the `Reducer` type (`(prevState: S, action: A) => S`) in your first code example, is this correct?

Comment: Does [this question about getting parameter types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299555/is-there-argumentstypet-like-returntypet-in-typescript) and [this question about getting return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015691/obtaining-the-return-type-of-a-function) assist at all?

Comment: You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/DmM36w), but I don't quite understand why you want this instead of the version you have? Is there some *advantage* to the more complex type juggling involved in inferring `S` and `A` from `R`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely what the `infer` keyword is for.  If you check out [the types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/93914ec9517be43190cb9d503712368f4d5f2151/types/react/v16/index.d.ts#L886) for the actual `useReducer` hook, you'll see that React is inferring the type for the `State` and the `Action` from the reducer function.

```
type ReducerState<R extends Reducer<any, any>> = R extends Reducer<infer S, any> ? S : never;
type ReducerAction<R extends Reducer<any, any>> = R extends Reducer<any, infer A> ? A : never;
```

We specify that the generic `R` must be some sort of reducer, aka `R extends Reducer<any, any>`, and then work backwards to get either if its generic variables.

The `useReducer` hook itself has a few different overloads, but basically it looks like this:

```
function useReducer<R extends Reducer<any, any>>(
    reducer: R
): [ReducerState<R>, Dispatch<ReducerAction<R>>];
```

Where the generic is the reducer function and the types for `State` and `Action` are derived from it.

Comment: Thanks a lot it was exactly what i was looking for