# Typescript strongly type a function with dynamic parameters passed to another function (React - debounce hook)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, debouncing

I'm trying to strongly type a function (F1) that is passed to another function (F2). F1 has a dynamic amount of parameters so I cannot define any specific type.

The function/hook I'm working on:

```js
export function useDebounceVoidFunction(func: (...params: any[]) => void, timeout: number): (...params: any[]) => void { // F2

    let timer: MutableRefObject<NodeJS.Timeout | undefined> = useRef();

    const debouncedFunction = useCallback((...params: any[]) => { // F1
        clearTimeout(timer.current);
        timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
            func(...params);
        }, timeout);
    }, [func, timeout])

    return debouncedFunction; // F1
}
```

This kind of works... but the parameters in F1 are now any. This mean I could supply a function with 2 parameters and then use the F1 with as many parameters as I want.

I tried using the Wildcard type (`useDebounceVoidFunction<T>(func: (...params: T[]) ...` but that doesn't work. I think `T` at that time is of type `unknown`.

Any suggestions on how I could solve this? Couldn't find any post that resolved my issue.

EDIT1: Added small playground and trying to use Parameter [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgTgcwM5QLxQArxgWwsCOJAHgAoA6SsbHALlgDsQBKNAPigG8BfNgbgBQAiAA8wAezjAoAMwCuDAMbAAluIZQ5SCABEIAI3ELFEAGriVAEwBix1etLyl9ClRpJ68ZK1QcAbhaWADRQqnhGwPQMcjj6hMwulOTUcLgesIhIPv6BXEJQBVAA9EVQADb4oSp4cPQAsnLAMPoVAEoQMgDy%20gBWEMrEAHLilhAAUgDK5AAq1RARUAA%20mgyjMioMEJYc6FoQ7TKkzIIChVBw%20HJwDK7J7p6Z2XlnZ06KpClpx6eF3ILcQje9g0EBwYFAtiUwNI0VihCiMTicBCSGAcA2CHoqPRDAQrE4PwKAgBAiBag0inE4jKE2Achkh3x%20UKlIYqKgo0Mxi2kOU5LQmm0ei5SjMgV50NB4JAEvJIQATAAGRXfbhAA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there ArgumentsType<T> like ReturnType<T> in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299555/is-there-argumentstypet-like-returntypet-in-typescript)

Comment: Hmm, I'm struggling with the syntax. Do you know how I should write my hook? Added a small playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function needs to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) corresponding to the function's parameter list.  You can give a [function a rest parameter of such a generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters):

```
function useDebounceVoidFunction<A extends any[]>
    (func: (...params: A) => void, timeout: number): (...params: A) => void {

    // let timer: MutableRefObject<NodeJS.Timeout | undefined> = useRef();

    return (...params: A) => {
        func(...params);
    };
}
```

Here, `A` is a generic type parameter which has been [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to an arraylike type (A for Arguments). And both the `func` callback and the return type have a `params` rest argument of type `A`.

When you call `useDebounceVoidFunction()`, the compiler will infer a tuple type for `A` corresponding to the ordered list of parameter types to the `func` argument:

```
function someFunc(number: number, string: string) {
    console.log(number.toFixed(2), string.toUpperCase())
}

function coolStuff() {
    const debouncedFunction = useDebounceVoidFunction(someFunc, 200);
    debouncedFunction(Math.PI, "abc") // "3.14", "ABC"
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAjAZwKYBEMCMGRQYBqCcAJgGKHxIA8AgshgB4wYTlrICGEAngG0AugD5gyScgAU4aAC4ZAOhUAHHgCceAWzSKGASmQBeUcgBuZcgBpk8bRgIxFEMNtwYNBxdJVL1Wrr6RqYWVsgA3sASUgD0scgANhgwdnAOGooAsmAwPLjJAEoYIADyuABWGLB0AHII5BgAUgDKSgAq6Y65yAA+qJwlcBAY5GbGqJjFINIGANzRUsgaKWAaKL5qmjp6yIYmZlFLS3JQm-7buvMxkgC+C7fRp7QoaAgO1NDSru6eLm4eDS2NAwDTDADmihBYIg4KMRykUCQb2SSkSCHB3wBniUMAQlDgLFG0gATAZgaCIbiEABVVSqTwAYR4mFmBmAj1ANEQKCRCESLRgYBAM3hN2QSIgIOQjXwhFGn1gPJMk2weAI0BIVkVL2kbw+hFsJIADMbrktZRqiFRuUhpFkeDAABZKAAKAElbAAifJQL1GeLIL0AZiUAEYACxe70MABCjK9HOifIFQpFszmQA)