# Function definition for a function that accepts a callback with various inputs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to write a function definition for a function that accepts a render callback and paramater that will be passed into the render callback. How can I ensure the parameter is one of my defined types?

This is the logic I have now:

```
const render1 = (chip: string): React.ReactElement => {...}
const render2 = (chip: { name: string, email: string}): React.ReactElement => {...}

const values1 = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
const render2 = [{name: "jim1" , email: "test@example.ca"}]

type chipTypes = string[] | { name: string, email: string }[];

type InputParams = {
  values: chipTypes;
  renderFun: (chip: ???) => React.ReactElement
}
```

I've passing both render function definitions as a union but it forces me to type add type guards at the top of each function, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there ArgumentsType<T> like ReturnType<T> in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299555/is-there-argumentstypet-like-returntypet-in-typescript)